# Transparant spritesheet animation for webgl

Tags: three.js, webgl, sprite-sheet

I'm just getting started with webgl and was trying to make an animation based on a spritesheet. I've found an example and changed the spritesheet to my own. However even though I removed the white background, saved it as a transparant png, the animation still shows up with a white background.

This is the example I used:
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-Animation.html

Is there any way how I can get rid off the white background?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
var runnerTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/run.png' );
annie = new TextureAnimator( runnerTexture, 10, 1, 10, 75 ); // texture, #horiz, #vert, #total, duration.
var runnerMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: runnerTexture, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );
var runnerGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50, 1, 1);
var runner = new THREE.Mesh(runnerGeometry, runnerMaterial);
runner.position.set(-150,25,0);
scene.add(runner);
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: It's exactly the same code as on the example page. I only changed the spritesheet.

Comment: Please include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. See also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Added a part of the code as it's too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support PNGs with an alpha-channel, you have to modify the `MeshBasicMaterial` accordingly: There is an attribute 'transparent' which you could set to 'true'.

Try using the following line instead:

```
var runnerMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: runnerTexture, side:THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true } );
```

See also the reference from [Material](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/Material):

> .transparent
>
> Defines whether this material is transparent. This has an effect on
>   rendering as transparent objects need special treatment and are
>   rendered after non-transparent objects. For a working example of this
>   behaviour, check the WebGLRenderer code.  When set to true, the extent
>   to which the material is transparent is controlled by setting opacity.